# React / nextjs query string passed through props to component does not seem to resolve

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, strapi

I have a nextjs sample app project.  A query is passed through props, but comes back "undefined"

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')

Source
components\RestaurantList\index.js (54:17) @ eval

  52 | 
  53 |     const searchQuery = data.restaurants.data.filter((query) => {
> 54 |       query.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.search)
     |                 ^
  55 |   });
```

In pages/index.js, I have:

```
function Home() {
**  const [query, updateQuery] = useState("");**
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <div className="search">
**            <InputGroup>
              <InputGroupAddon addonType="append"> Search </InputGroupAddon>
              <Input
                onChange={e => updateQuery(e.target.value.toLocaleLowerCase())}
                value={query}
              />
            </InputGroup>**
          </div>

**          <RestaurantList search={query} />**
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

In my components/RestaurantList, I have

```
function RestaurantList(props) {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(QUERY);
  if (error) return "Error loading restaurants";
  //if restaurants are returned from the GraphQL query, run the filter query
  //and set equal to variable restaurantSearch
  if (loading) return <h1>Fetching</h1>;
  if (data.restaurants.data && data.restaurants.data.length) {
    console.log(`restaurant list is ${data.restaurants.data}`);
    //searchQuery

**    const searchQuery = data.restaurants.data.filter((query) => {
      query.name.toLowerCase().includes(props.search)
  });**
  
  //const searchQuery = `a ${props.search}`;
    if (searchQuery.length != 0) {
      return (
```

...

I have tried using console.log to see what props has or if query is null.  It seems to be empty

Comment: You get an error because `query.name` is `undefined`. `query` is not a prop

Comment: Please show the GraphQL query you're running. Also try `console.log(data)` to ascertain the shape of the result. You'll want to be sure that you're filtering something which is an actual array.